# Scatter container over container's graphic representation

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

In Kivy, I have a scatter object in a Tab Panel.
I can freely move the objects inside the scatter, but they can be moved on the whole window, I want to restrict the shifting on the parent's size (or at least, to draw the scatter below the parent, not hiding it).
Here is the problem I see
[image: moving the rectangle inside container]
[image: moving the rectangle outside container, hiding it]

I don't want the rectangle to go outside the panel and mask the panel's title.

Is this a way to do this?

Here is the code for this example

```
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = Builder.load_string("""
<RootWidget>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Test'

        Screen:
            Scatter:
                Widget:
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgb: (1, 1, 0)
                        Rectangle:
""")


class RootWidget(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class ScatterProblemApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScatterProblemApp().run()
```

Comment: I found an option: inserting a  `StencilView` between the `Screen` and the `Scatter`. I don't know if it's the right way to do this

Comment: Try packing the `Scatter` widget into a layout that inherits from `StencilView`, then put the layout on the `Screen`.